# Is it possible for my DVI-HDMI converter to be causing applications on my G-Sync Monitor (on DisplayPort) to flash black?

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, hdmi, dvi

For reference, I'm using a total of 3 monitors: One 60Hz tablet (the one that's hooked up using the DVI to HDMI), a 75Hz FreeSync monitor, and a 60Hz monitor. When I have the two monitors hooked up alone, I don't have any issues, but when I hook my tablet up, every so often an application using G-Sync will flash black for a fraction of a second and go back to normal, which is severely irritating. Is it possible that my converter could be the cause of this?

Answer (score 0):

It is unlikely that your DVI to HDMI converter is the cause of the issue, but there isnt enough information to be sure.  DVI to HDMI converters can be either active or passive.  If it is passive, its very unlikely, as the video signal is being passed straight through.  Active adapters do have circuitry in them to boost the signal, but that really shouldnt affect the display on another port.  However, if there was something wrong with the active adapter or the tablet you are using as a display is sending back some strange signal, I could see it having an affect on the display its connected to, but not another.

The only way to really find out the answer is to do tests with known good hardware, but that might not be feasible or practical for you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. While I haven't had the chance to do any in-depth testing yet, I do have a little more information. I uploaded a video (https://youtu.be/msLNdAzukB4) that shows that the black flashes occur more often when framerates are lower; at 75, they happen once every few minutes, but here I show two within seconds when forcing to 20FPS. Additionally, this had to be captured off-screen, as it's not seen by software. I know that G-Sync is set to shut off below a certain framerate, could that be the issue, and is it fixable?